# ¿Por qué mi div no se centra?

Tags: html5, css3, div, img

Como se ve en el código, primero cree un `img`, luego encerré 1 imagen en un div y por útlimo otras 3 en otro div.

```
<img src="../imagenes/bannerCosta.jpg">
<div>
    <img src="../imagenes/comida_1.jpg">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="../imagenes/comida_2.jpg">
    <img src="../imagenes/comida_3.jpg">
    <img src="../imagenes/comida_4.jpg">
</div>
```

Posteriormente en la etiqueta `<style>`:

```
<style>

body {
    background-color: azure;
}

h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: darkblue;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 13pt;
}

div {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

p a {
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: red;
}                                             
</style>
```

- Ajuste el ancho de la primera imagen.
  `img { width: 100%; }`
- Luego ajuste el ancho de los div y a su vez quise centrarlos:

  `div { width: 20%; text-align: center; }`

Sin embargo, las 4 últimas imágenes de mi página, que son justamente las que estan dentro de los div, no estan centradas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ando aprendiendo hace poco HTML y CSS, y me encontré con este problema. Ayuden por favor.

Comment: Agrega margin: auto; en el div.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que hacerlos flexibles a los elementos de ese `div` que encierra a tus 4 imágenes y centrarlos con `justify-content: center` y `align-items: center`.

---

Primero, voy a reproducir tu problema:

```css
body {
  background-color: azure;
}

h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: darkblue;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 13pt;
}

div {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

p a {
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" height="200px">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae semper purus. Donec eu auctor turpis, a dignissim neque. Donec pulvinar rutrum aliquet. Vestibulum nec nulla eu odio tristique fermentum. Aliquam placerat augue sed libero euismod, sit amet molestie libero pulvinar. Sed sit amet lorem non magna fermentum semper. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus dapibus pretium diam, sit amet sodales ex. Morbi tincidunt mi ac leo lacinia, eget fermentum lacus condimentum. Donec feugiat lacinia nulla in dictum. Vivamus congue, leo id cursus dignissim, ex est vestibulum urna, cursus porta nulla tortor vitae nunc. Aenean volutpat quis nulla vel gravida.</p>
<div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae semper purus. Donec eu auctor turpis, a dignissim neque. Donec pulvinar rutrum aliquet. Vestibulum nec nulla eu odio tristique fermentum. Aliquam placerat augue sed libero euismod, sit amet molestie libero pulvinar. Sed sit amet lorem non magna fermentum semper. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus dapibus pretium diam, sit amet sodales ex. Morbi tincidunt mi ac leo lacinia, eget fermentum lacus condimentum. Donec feugiat lacinia nulla in dictum. Vivamus congue, leo id cursus dignissim, ex est vestibulum urna, cursus porta nulla tortor vitae nunc. Aenean volutpat quis nulla vel gravida.</p>
<div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae semper purus. Donec eu auctor turpis, a dignissim neque. Donec pulvinar rutrum aliquet. Vestibulum nec nulla eu odio tristique fermentum. Aliquam placerat augue sed libero euismod, sit amet molestie libero pulvinar. Sed sit amet lorem non magna fermentum semper. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus dapibus pretium diam, sit amet sodales ex. Morbi tincidunt mi ac leo lacinia, eget fermentum lacus condimentum. Donec feugiat lacinia nulla in dictum. Vivamus congue, leo id cursus dignissim, ex est vestibulum urna, cursus porta nulla tortor vitae nunc. Aenean volutpat quis nulla vel gravida.</p>
```

Y le agregaré una clase al `div` que encierra a tus 4 imágenes, llamémosle `.contenedor`:

```
<div class ="contenedor">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
</div>
<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
</div>
```

Y le agrego las siguientes propiedades:

```
.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.contenedor img {
  width: 20%;
}
```

Aquí indico que tus 4 elementos, serán flexibles (uno al lado del otro, con `display: flex`), serán justificados al centro (con `justify-content: center`) y también alineados al centro (con `align-items:center`). A ese `.contenedor` que encierra tus 4 elementos, le indico que ocupe el ancho del `100%` con `width: 100%;` para que tus imágenes estén centrados en ese `100%` del ancho (toda la pantalla), y las imágenes solo ocuparán el `20%` del ancho de ese `100%` (ese cambio solo le afecta a las imágenes que están dentro de `.contenedor` para que no afecte a las demás, es por eso que ingreso así: `.contenedor img { ... }`). Y por último, el `gap: 10px;` es para dar una separación de `10px` entre las imágenes, para tener un mejor resultado.

---

Ejemplo:

```css
body {
  background-color: azure;
}

h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: darkblue;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 13pt;
}

div {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

p a {
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: red;
}

.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.contenedor img {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" height="200px">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae semper purus. Donec eu auctor turpis, a dignissim neque. Donec pulvinar rutrum aliquet. Vestibulum nec nulla eu odio tristique fermentum. Aliquam placerat augue sed libero euismod, sit amet molestie libero pulvinar. Sed sit amet lorem non magna fermentum semper. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus dapibus pretium diam, sit amet sodales ex. Morbi tincidunt mi ac leo lacinia, eget fermentum lacus condimentum. Donec feugiat lacinia nulla in dictum. Vivamus congue, leo id cursus dignissim, ex est vestibulum urna, cursus porta nulla tortor vitae nunc. Aenean volutpat quis nulla vel gravida.</p>
<div class ="contenedor">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae semper purus. Donec eu auctor turpis, a dignissim neque. Donec pulvinar rutrum aliquet. Vestibulum nec nulla eu odio tristique fermentum. Aliquam placerat augue sed libero euismod, sit amet molestie libero pulvinar. Sed sit amet lorem non magna fermentum semper. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus dapibus pretium diam, sit amet sodales ex. Morbi tincidunt mi ac leo lacinia, eget fermentum lacus condimentum. Donec feugiat lacinia nulla in dictum. Vivamus congue, leo id cursus dignissim, ex est vestibulum urna, cursus porta nulla tortor vitae nunc. Aenean volutpat quis nulla vel gravida.</p>
<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png">
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae semper purus. Donec eu auctor turpis, a dignissim neque. Donec pulvinar rutrum aliquet. Vestibulum nec nulla eu odio tristique fermentum. Aliquam placerat augue sed libero euismod, sit amet molestie libero pulvinar. Sed sit amet lorem non magna fermentum semper. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus dapibus pretium diam, sit amet sodales ex. Morbi tincidunt mi ac leo lacinia, eget fermentum lacus condimentum. Donec feugiat lacinia nulla in dictum. Vivamus congue, leo id cursus dignissim, ex est vestibulum urna, cursus porta nulla tortor vitae nunc. Aenean volutpat quis nulla vel gravida.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que le estas asignando a los div ( a todos ) con la regla `div { width: 20%; text-align: center; }` y a las imagenes un 100% por lo que ocuparan el 100% de los 20% del width del div, por lo que quedaran en forma de columna, lo correcto para que ya no pase esto (ademas de claro evitar `style="width: 100%;"` ) en los elementos es el uso de
[Clases e IDs en CSS: Cuándo y cómo usarlas](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/clases-ids-css-cuando-como-usarlas.aspx)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<style>

body {
    background-color: azure;
}

h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: darkblue;
}


p {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 13pt;
}


p a {
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: red;
}  
div{
    text-align:center;
}                                           
</style>


<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" style="width: 100%;">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x360">
</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div> 
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x360">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x360">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x360">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

en tu archivo .css estás asignando a los `div` un width:20% del espacio de su padre, asi que al colocar  a las etiquetas img un width: 100% en realidad estan ocupando el 100% del div que a su vez ocupa solo el 20% de su padre correspondiente.

Creo que lo mas sencillo es que dejes el `div` del tamaño completo y si quieres tu imagen más pequeña, coloca el width que deseas para esta y así si va a estar centrado dentro del div, en este momento está centrada en el div, pero el div no está centrado con respecto a su padre.